# Filter KStream records based on values of another topic

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to filter KStream new messages of a topic A based on messages of another topic B?
The real question is if I can keep all messages of topic B in a structure(for example list of objects)**, not only new messages but always all messages**, so I can filter the messages of topic A based on topic B.
I tried a foreach loop for messages of topic B KStream inside a filter method of topic A KStream but it did not work as KStream of topic B doesn't hold all messages.